# When does $\langle \hat A \hat B \rangle =\langle\hat A \rangle \langle \hat B\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability

In ordinary probability theory the relation:
$$E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$$
holds when $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated (or independent). The analogous relation in quantum mechanics is:
$$\newcommand{\p}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}} \newcommand{\f}[2]{\frac{ #1}{ #2}} \newcommand{\l}[0]{\left(} \newcommand{\r}[0]{\right)} \newcommand{\mean}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}\mean{\hat A \hat B}=\mean{\hat A} \mean{\hat B}$$
my question is when in general does this hold?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\langle \hat{A} \hat{B} \rangle = \langle \Psi | \hat{A} \hat{B} | \Psi \rangle  \\
\langle \hat{A}\rangle \langle \hat{B} \rangle = \langle \Psi | \hat{A}  | \Psi \rangle \langle \Psi | \hat{B}  | \Psi \rangle
$$
That means for the equation to hold, you need 
$$
\hat{A} | \Psi \rangle \langle \Psi |\hat{B} = \hat{A} \hat{B}
$$

In general the equation holds if $|\Psi \rangle$ is an eigenstate of both of the operators.

Comment: It is sufficient. I edited my post.